# Calculating edge lengths of triangles obtained from Delaunay's triangulation

Tags: c++, opencv, delaunay

I have a set of discrete points and using them, I performed Delaunay's triangulation.

I want to calculate all the edge lengths from a vertex to the neighboring vertices.

How can I do/code this in c++?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to be more specific about your issue. Show us what you have done so far and where you got stuck at. Providing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is also important.

Comment: Thanks!
I got the code for delaunay triangulation from [here](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/Delaunay)

Which helped me get all the triangles. I want to calculate the length of all the edges/lines which connect a vertex to its surrounding vertices. Imagine a point at the centre of a hexagon which is joined with hexagon's corners dividing the hexagon into 6 triangles.

I am unable to add image to make the question more clear.

Comment: It is still unclear what you want us to do. You have not specified what exactly you are stuck on. Do you know how to calculate the distance between two points? Once you have a function for that, it's only a matter of picking the right point pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code that you posted, but the problem seems trivial.

1. In your `main` function after you draw all the triangles/points, get the list of all the triangles from `subdiv` with:

   ```
   vector<Vec6f> triangleList; 
   subdiv.getTriangleList(triangleList);
   ```

   (just like in the `draw_delaunay(...)` function)
2. Now you just iterate the triangles and compare each point of each triangle to your vertex.
3. If it's the same point as yours, then you calculate the lengths of edges with two other points of the triangle. 
   Length here = L2 norm of the vector `v = point - your_vertex` = `Sqrt(v.x^2 + v.y^2)`.

There may be duplicates of some edges, so if you want to avoid it, just create a set and add all the point there and calculate the norms later.